# Use only `await` instead `await MainActor.run { }` for @MainActor properties

Tags: swift, swiftui

Let assume a ObservableObject as the following:

```swift
class NavigationModel: ObservableObject {
  @MainActor @Published name: String = ""
}
```

When changing the published property within an async code block running **not** in the main queue, I am normally using the following syntax:

```swift
await MainActor.run {
  name = "foobar"
}
```

However, I have realised that the following syntax can also be compiled without errors:

```swift
await name = "foobar"
```

I am wondering if this short path is valid and provides same results?

Comment: Depends on context, but the first variant is for the case when there is no explicit main actor property wrapper (so for you it is redundant).

Comment: So just writing „await“ is proper syntax that achieves the same result? The code behind „await“ will be executed on global actor within main queue, but not the code beyond this line?

Comment: "but not the code beyond this line" You have not shown any code beyond that line. There is no way, given nothing but tiny snippets, to know what such code might be, what it might do, or what its execution context might be. For all we know, both `MainActor` specifications might be superfluous. If you want help, show your _real_ code and ask your _real_ question.

Comment: They are not the same thing. Perhaps you found some context in which you can get away either without an error, but in my examples, I have to choose one or the other, whichever is appropriate for the current context, but not both. but without a MCVE, we cannot comment. E.g., https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcmJ2.png. (BTW, actor behaviors have been evolving, and even more changes are coming in Swift 6, so please include info regarding what version of Swift you are using.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the two snippets will behave the same.
The `await` will cause the current asynchronous call to "hop" the main actor and execute there.

The compiler (and Swift runtime) know that `name` can only be accessed from the main thread/actor, so will require you to either:

1. Access the property from an asynchronous block with `@MainActor` context.
2. Hop to the main actor from the current thread to execute there. Then, resume execution of the current function afterwards (however, the function could resume on a different thread than it was originally executing on prior to the hop to the main actor).

Your first snippet is essentially doing both of these steps, introducing a `@MainActor` scope to run your code in, then you are hopping to the main actor to execute it before continuing with your function call.
The second snippet is just skipping the scope creation part, running the single line of code on the main actor, then hopping back right away.

If you're running multiple things on the main actor you will want to reduce the number of hops that are performed, because this will introduce a lot of overhead if you are hopping back-and-forth to and from the main actor.
For example:

```swift
@MainActor func someUIOperation() async { ... }

func expensiveLotsOfHopsToMainActor() async {
    for _ in 0..<100 {
        await someUIOperation()
    }
}

func betterOnlyOneHopToMainActor() async {
    await MainActor.run {
        for _ in 0..<100 {
           someUIOperation()
        }
    }
}
```

See examples and more in the [original pitch for `@MainActor`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0316-global-actors.md#the-main-actor).

Comment: This does not seem to work for me without explicitly adding `MainActor.run`. I get `'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency` from `expensiveLotsOfHopsToMainActor`.